# Binding Separate Groups of JSON Data to a UserID Number AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, object

I've been having trouble figuring out how to keep data as separate forms, but binding together inside of angularJS.  This is for educational and testing purposes so I don't need to worry about setting this data to a db or using any type of storage for now other than the apps session and localstorage.  For the test I will hard code into my JS.

I'm uploading a photo to showcase my thoughts and I'll explain it as well:  [image: showcasing data structures i want to achieve]

So my main data is a customers group.  I have it set to iterate through and display using ng-repeat.  No big worries there.  I can add, and update each of these.  When I had the proposals attached to the customers json object then when I edited the user, it would delete those proposals and quotes.  So I want to keep them separate, but allow them to be called into the DOM by specific user.

**My Problem:** 
Is that I do not know how to bind objects, to objects, and have them update in the dom anytime another action happens.  Here is a pen of what I have so far 
http://codepen.io/ddavisgraphics/pen/pvRZOv?editors=101.

Example of the Code Data:

```
var customerArray = [
    // Start Customer 
    //--------------
    {
        customerID:1,
        customer: 'Joe Frankelton',
        phone: 1244957323,
        email: 'jFrank@gmail.com',
        // start address 
        address: { 
            line1:'248 Gallows Rd',
            city:'Hangtown', 
            state:'West HangState',
            zip:24750
        },
    }, // End Customer 
     // Start Customer 
    //--------------
    {
        customerID:2,
        customer: 'Danny Manny',
        phone: 1245423323,
        email: 'dman@gmail.com',
        // start address 
        address: { 
            line1:'253 Cow Run Rd',
            city:'Beeftown', 
            state:'PA',
            zip:24750
        },
    }, // End Customer 
];

var  proposals = [
            { // Proposal 1 
                customerID: 1,
                projectTitle: 'Gameify Me Captin',
                type: 'GameDesign',
                deadline: 'Jan. 2, 2015',
                deliveryType: 'Files',
                problem: 'The problem is that the customer wants to much crap.',
                notes: 'clients mother wants to be involved because she designed a peice of toast in 1973',
            },
            { // Proposal 2
                customerID: 2,
                projectTitle: 'Playing',
                type: 'Website',
                deadline: 'Jan. 2, 2017',
                deliveryType: 'Sites',
                problem: 'Everything',
                notes: 'client will be easy to work with, wants pink and blue',
            },
        ]; 

  var quotes = [
            {
                customerID: 2,
                quoteNum: 2,
                projectTitle: 'Project Title',
                type: 'Graphic Design',
                deadline: 'Jan. 2, 2015',
                billableHrs: 11,
                hourlyRate: 42.50,
                externalCost: 33.99,
                tax: 0.6,
            }
    ];
```

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the issue? The pen looks good to me.

Comment: I don't know how to link the data in the quotes, and proposals objects with the customer data using the customerID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create a viewmodel for customer by mapping the data from multiple sources, i.e customers, proposals and quotes.

You can use customerID to do the linking, example:

```
customer.proposals = proposals.filter(function(prop){ 
       return prop.customerID === custId;
 });
```

So you would do:

```
function getMappedCustomer() {
     return customerArray.map(function(customer){
        var custId = customer.customerID;
        customer.proposals = proposals.filter(function(prop){ return prop.customerID === custId;});
        customer.quotes = quotes.filter(function(quot){ return quot.customerID === custId;  });
        return customer;
     });
  }
  // Init current data
  $scope.customers = getMappedCustomer();
```

Similarly do it when you do the maping of updated customer. If you want to preserve `customerArray` use `angular.copy(customerArray)` and do the mapping on it.

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNKYbe)**

Comment: On the localcopy on my machine it throws a syntax error.  it says that the angular forEach isn't represented correctly, but won't show exactly where.

Comment: Are you using angular.forEach ? what is the exact error in the console?

Comment: I had to adjust it slightly. 

`function getMappedCustomer(){
      angular.forEach(customerArray, function(customer){
        var custId = customer.customerID;
        customer.proposals = proposals.filter(function(prop){ return prop.customerID === custId;  });
        customer.quotes = quotes.filter(function(quot){ return quot.customerID === custId;  });
    
     });
      return customerArray;
    }`

Comment: Yeah that is fine, what is the issue? forEach, map etc are native, ecmascript5 standard not supported in older browsers without the help of shim.

Comment: No problem now, I'm using grunt and JSHint wouldn't pass the forEach with the way it was so I had to change it to angular forEach in order for everything to render without an error. Thank you for your help!